# Modified A-Z grouping

Tags: craft3, entries, merge

I'm trying to output the alphabet where certain letters are enabled/clickable based on whether any entries from a specific section start with that letter. Here's the UI:
[image]

Getting the A-Z is easy enough:

```
{% set letterArray = 'A'..'Z' %}
```

And I'm able to get the entries by first letter:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myEntries').orderBy('title asc').all() %}
{% set entriesByGroup = entries|group('title[:1]') %}
{% for firstLetter, entriesInGroup in entriesByGroup %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I just can't figure out how to properly merge them so I can set a class or whatever on the letters that have at least an entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looping over the letters in the range, you should be able to use the `keys` filter to check if the current letter is in the `entriesByGroup` array. If it is, you can link it or add a class, etc.

```
{% set letterArray = 'A'..'Z' %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myEntries').orderBy('title asc').all() %}
{% set entriesByGroup = entries|group('title[:1]') %}

{% for letter in letterArray %}
   {% if letter in entriesByGroup|keys %}
      {# this letter has at least one entry, anchor link, add a class #}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 
{% for firstLetter, entriesInGroup in entriesByGroup %}
   {# your alphabetical entry listing %}
{% endfor %}
```

I do something similar here on the [CraftQuest Archive page](https://craftquest.io/archive) but with a slightly different approach ([here's a video on it](https://craftquest.io/courses/creating-content-archives/5423)).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Ryan (assuming it's Ryan ). I wasn't familiar with the `keys` filter. That did what I needed. Will definitely watch the video you linked to.

Comment: It's me! You're welcome. :)